# Connecting Hotjar to PowerBI as a data source

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, hotjar

I am looking for a way to connect Hotjar to PowerBI where if I get a new answer to a survey it will update the dashboard automatically, is there anyway to actually do this? via an API or any other method?

Edit: hotjar currently doesn't offer that via powerBI but I really need it!

Answer (score 0):

There are currently, two options.

- Integration via Slack/Zapier as offered by HotJar
- Your own parsing script that will click on 'Export list to CSV/XLS' periodically.

I prefer to use my own parsing script as it is simple enough and there is no need to pay for other services (or check if I'm still in free tier)